# Recommended way of talking to a Django application URL, from within a view of the same application?

Tags: django, view

I have a Django application, and need to deal with the following:

- One of my views, needs to make a POST request to another URL endpoint of the same application.
- In order to do so, I use the `requests` module. I assemble the URL of the endpoint I need to call, dump the POST parameters, and perform the call.
- This works fine for the most part, however fails miserably when testing, since the view that corresponds to the URL that I talk to, knows nothing about the state of the testing environment.

The code is similar to this:

```
from django.conf import settings
import json
def view1(request, *args, **kwargs):
    url = 'http://api.%s/view2/' % settings.DOMAIN      
    r = requests.post(
        url,
        data=json.dumps({'key': 'value'}),
    )      
    // Notice that the ``url`` is a url of the actual deployed application, 
    // and therefore knows nothing about testing and its state. That's where 
    // it goes wrong.
```

The question is, is there a way that this can behave correctly in testing? I use the `django.test.client.Client` class for creating my test requests. As far as I know, instances of this class talk directly to the URL mapper. Therefore the `url` that I construct in the view is simply an external http request to the deployed application, instead of the **tested** application.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the exact issue that you face when testing? Context propagation?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Exactly. The request that will end up in ``url``, carries session data associated with the testing environment. The question is whether (in testing) the ``url`` can be constructed in a way such that the request to ``url`` will end up being served by the testing environment.

Comment: I don't know enough to comment on the testing bits of django; but an alternate could be a tool like [`httpie`](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie) which I highly recommend.

Comment: @dm03514: You are absolutely right. The ``url`` can be pretty much any url of any external service. Right now I deploy this service along with my Django application. However I plan to deploy it separately (most likely to some Google App Engine instance), and therefore I prefer to have a more generic setup from early on.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to mock the response from the URL for the purposes of the tests. I'd suggest using a lightweight mocking library, such as this:

http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2011-11-07-a-flyweight-mocking-helper-for-python.html

See the example code. It's very similar to your situation. I've used both of these in combination with requests and flask, but not django.

Comment: Thank you for the answer David. That's a very good workaround!